# Можно прописать в html, чтобы консоль была открыта по умолчанию

Tags: html, консоль

То есть при открытии сайта, косоль уже была бы видна

Comment: ............нет

Comment: Через код вряд ли, но можно настроить сам браузер на автооткрытие консоли. [Пример для Хрома на Линуксе](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22085635/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D0%A1-linux?hl=ru)

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы у всех пользователей Вашего сайта была открыта консоль?

Answer (score 2):

Самый реалистичный способ если нужно следить за console.log - написать свой обработчик и добавить какую-нибудь верстку на страницу в виде консоли. На stackoverflow в сниппетах такая же реализация.

Вы не можете управлять браузером из html или js, если только это не selenium или какое-то подобное средство - но это к вопросу мало отношения имеет

Ниже я привел упрощенный пример реализации (время в миллисекундах будет не совпадать, просто демонстрация)

Важная деталь, до того как выполнится строка `console.log = oldConsoleLog` можно вводить данные через консоль браузера, для этого достаточно прописать там вызов console.log c нужными аргументами.

```js
const cons = document.getElementById('console');
const oldConsoleLog = console.log // сохраняем оригинальную функцию

const getTimeString = () => {
 const date = new Date()
 return '|'  + (date.getHours()) + 
   ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' +  date.getSeconds() +
   '.' +  `${date.getMilliseconds()}`.padStart(3, 0);
}

// обертка над стандартной консолью
console.log =  function(...args){
  cons.innerHTML += args.map(e => JSON.stringify(e, null, 2)) .join(' ') 
    + getTimeString().padStart(20, ' ') + '\n'
  oldConsoleLog(...args) // вывод в браузерную консоль
} 

console.log(1,2,3) // вывод в обе консоли
console.log([1]) // вывод массива в обе консоли
console.log = oldConsoleLog // возвращаем все как было
console.log(456) // вывод только в браузерную консоль
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 5px;    
}
```

```html
<pre id="console"></pre>
```